# How to build an App with React-Native and integrate c++ module for faster performance

Tags: android, c++, react-native

Till now I have used
 `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`
After this I created a Directory called `MyNativeModules` in which I created two files `Squarerootmodule.cpp`  and `Squarerootmodule.h`.I would like to connect this to a file to the frontend.I want to know how to use this cpp file in my App.js file and use its functions .
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLxCX.png)

I found a method by editing the build.gride but I did not understand that also is there any other way without using android studio

Comment: The following instructions explain how to use React Native to create an application and use a C++ library for enhanced speed:
Make a fresh React Native application.
Go to NativeModules/ios/NativeModule.xcworkspace in Xcode after opening it.
Make a fresh C++ file called Cpp_to_RN.cpp.
Export the C++ files to the iOS (swift) side after wrapping them.
To use React Native, export the C++ function.
Call the functions of the Swift class and import React from'react';